# Keeping classes loosely coupled and sharing data

Tags: python, class, loose-coupling

I've been working in python on a project where I have a GUI which I split up a bunch of the work between classes. I don't know a lot of the best practices for passing data around between classes, and I've frequently run into the issue, where I have to implement something, or change something for work, and I've resorted to making a lot of the classes objects of another class in order to give it the data I need.

Any ideas or suggests would be greatly appreciated on how to keep my classes independent for later modification and still pass the relevant data around without affecting interfaces too much?

**As an example**

```
class Window():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
    def doStuff(self):
        #do work here

class ParseMyWork(Window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent=parent
```

I often find myself doing stuff like the above giving objects to class *Window*
or simply inheriting everything from them as in *ParseMyWork*

There must be better and cleaner ways of passing data around without making my classes utterly dependent on eachother, where one little change creates a cascade effect that forces me to make changes in a bunch of other classes.

**Any answers to the question don't necessarily have to be in python, but it will be helpful if they are**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I would say that inheritance is not necessary in your case. Why not give `ParseMyWork` a function for dealing with a specific `Window` task?

```
class Window():
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.parent = parent

  def doStuff(self):
    #do work here

class ParseMyWork():
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.parent=parent`

  def doWindowActivity(self, window):
    window.doStuff
```

Then you can use the function like this

```
    work_parser = ParseMyWork()
    window = Window()
    work_parser.doWindowActivity(window);
```

That way you can use your work_parse instance with any window instance.

Apologies in advance for my Python, it's been a while so if you see any rookie mistakes, do point them out.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered passing a class directly to a function and having it taken care of right there with no outside references. That would probably work okay for my purposes.

Comment: Yea I think functions will be the trick here. Knowing when to use inheritance can be tricky, but I think in your case a couple of well written functions will do just fine, that way you don't have to worry about cascading effects if you change your base class. If you have a specific problem in mind or some more sample code I'd be happy to work it into my answer

Comment: This will work fine the way it is. I have way to much code to condense it into a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.py:

```
def doStuff(window):
    #do work here
    return window

def parseStuff(stuff):
    pass
```

really.py:

```
from simple import doStuff, parseStuff

def really_simple(window):
    okay = doStuff(window)
    return parseStuff(okay)
```

don't complicate the class:

```
from really import really_simple
really_simple(window)
```

imo: classes are overly complicated objects, and in a lot of cases more confusing than they need to be, plus they hold references and modify stuff, and can be difficult to decouple once they have been tied to other classes. if there isn't a clear reason why a class needs to be used, then it probably doesn't need to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are super powerful, so it's good you're getting started with em.

Discalimer: Haven't worked in python for a while now, so things might not be exact. The general idea still applies though.

Getting into your question now:

I would say the best way to achieve what you want is to create an instance of the first object where you will extract information from.

Now when creating a class, it's vital that you have attributes within them that you will want to be stored within it that you would like to retrieve once the class is instantiated.

For example, using your Window class example above, let's say that you have an attribute called resolution. It would look something like this:

```
    class Window():
      def __init__(self, parent = None):
         self.parent = None
         self.resolution = '40x80'
```

Now the resolution information associated with your Window class is forever part of any Window class instance. Now, the next step would be to create a get method for resolution. This should be done as follow:

```
    class Window():
      def __init__(self, parent = None):
         self.parent = None
         self.resolution = '40x80'

      def getResoultion():
         return self.resolution
```

Now, the reason we created this get method is because we can now set a variable to the information that is returned with it.

So let's say that you have everything associated with your Window class in its own file (let's say the file name is called Window.py). In a separate file (let's call it main.py), you can do the following:

```
    import Window

    windowInstance = Window()
    windowResolution = windowInstance.getResolution()
```

If you print out the variable windowResolution, you should get that 40x80 printed out.

Now, as a side note, I do believe it is possible to get the information associated with an attribute with an instance of a class by simply doing something like

```
     windowResolution = windowInstance.resolution
```

but that is bad practice in general. The reason, in a nutshell, is because you are now exposing attribute names of your class which you do not want to do because it makes it easy for a person outside of your code to learn the name where that information is held and change it. This can then lead to a myriad of other problems when it comes to making an overall program work. That is why it is best practice to use getters and setters. I already showed what getters are. Simply a get method for attributes. Setters, as you can probably assume, allow for one to set the information of an attribute to something else. Now you might say "Gabe, if we can create setter methods, what's the point of it if they just change it". My answer to that is to not give a setter method to all attributes. For attributes you don't mind for a person to change, give it a setter method, but for attributes you do not want any outside users to touch, simply don't create a setter method for it. Same goes with getter methods too. Users don't need to see all of the information of all attributes that makes your program work. Here's a better explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

Now, back to your example. Now let's say you have your ParseMyWork class in its own file like we did with your Window class, and let's say that ParseMyWork needs the resolution info from Window class. You can do the following :

```
    import Window
    import ParseMyWork

    windowInstance = Window()
    windowResolution = windowInstance.getResolution()

    parseInstance = ParseMyWork(windowResolution)
```

This will only pass the window resolution information associated with your Window class. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've never actually used get and set methods within a class before, as I never really thought there was much use. I'm still kind of leery of their use, although I'm coming around to them now. It would make modifying names, and datatypes (not as relevant in python) much easier to do. I haven't used them at all in my code. But, I probably should be.

Comment: When I first started working with classes, I was also very reluctant to use getters and setters. I thought they had very little use and were a waste of time. I have come around to using them over this past year since I first learned of classes simply because, I feel, they make my code look cleaner and also for what I had mentioned above.  It will make things easier to follow cause you can trace easier. I know it's a bear, but trust me